# How to create a dynamic row by skipping first row in a table

Tags: javascript, html

I want to create a new row in the below `tbody` but after the first row (`"aaaaa"`).

```
<html>
    <body onload="generate()">
        <table id="myTable">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>My Header</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="myList">
                <tr>
                    <td>aaaaa</td> 
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </body>
    <script>
        function generate(){            
            var node = document.createElement("tr");
            node.setAttribute("id","one");
            var textnodeTD = document.createElement("td");
            var values = document.createTextNode("AAAAA");
            document.getElementById("myList").lastChild(node);
            document.getElementById("one").appendChild(textnodeTD);
            textnodeTD.appendChild(values);  
        }
    </script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

Change the `lastChild` to `appendChild`

```js
function generate() {
  var node = document.createElement("tr");
  node.setAttribute("id", "one");
  var textnodeTD = document.createElement("td");
  var values = document.createTextNode("AAAAA");
  document.getElementById("myList").appendChild(node);
  document.getElementById("one").appendChild(textnodeTD);
  textnodeTD.appendChild(values);
}
```

```html
<body onload="generate()">
  <table id="myTable">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>My Header</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="myList">
      <tr>
        <td>aaaaa</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>
```